# VB.NET compress decompress string and return in string format

Tags: vb.net, text, compression

I need a vb.net function for compressing/decompressing a string, and return the result as a string. I found these two functions:

```
//Compress
Dim mem As New IO.MemoryStream
Dim gz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(mem, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(gz)
sw.WriteLine("hello compression")
sw.Close()

//Decompress
Dim mem2 As New IO.MemoryStream(mem.ToArray)
gz = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(mem2, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(gz)
MsgBox(sr.ReadLine)
sr.Close()
```

But how do I make them return the compressed string as a string? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to Base64 encode the compressed byte array to get a string representation.

```
Dim compressed As String = Convert.ToBase64String(mem.ToArray())
```

The decompressed string can just be read from the `StreamReader`.

```
Dim decompressed As String = sr.ReadLine()
```

Comment: @Qix - my apologies.  I'm in a lazy kind of mood today.  Fixed.

Comment: Great thanks :) would not the base 64 encoding lengthen the string size?

Comment: Yes, but the compressed bytes are just binary data which can't be handled safely in a string format by themselves.